# How to Paginate json response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, handlebars.js

I am currently working on a application ,where i will make a call to a url and get JSON response.i am using Handlebars.js to create a list li and finally append it to a ul. since the json reponse is huge , the requirement is to display the data in a pagination format.can you guys please guide me how to show the li's in a pagination format.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Pagniate json data </title>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
   <ul class="list-group">

   </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
 <!-- Handlebars.js -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Handlebar Template for creating the list -->
 <script id="list-group-item-template" type="text/template" >
     {{#each this}}
        <li class="list-group-item"> {{ title }} </li>
        {{/each}}
 </script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
             method:"GET",
             url:"http://starlord.hackerearth.com/cognizantinternal/hackernews",
             success:function(data){
                  //removing the first element from the response array
                  data.shift();
                  var template = Handlebars.compile($('#list-group-item-template').html());
                  var list = template(data);
                  $('.list-group').append(list);
             }
       });
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the response is huge then paginating on the client isn't going to speed anything up - you need to paginate on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case it would be better to do pagination on server side. Otherwise you can store json in local storage and perform pagination. Clear local storage after this request is completed

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should paginate on the request that you send to the server(e.g. provide a limit of `n` number when you send the AJAX request, usually as a query params).

Then, provide a `Load More` button to send another request to the server, or even better fetch the data again when user scroll down to the bottom of the page.